# Email notification on submission (response) to Excel Survey

Tags: excel, office365, survey, vba

How can I receive an email notification every time a submission is made to an online Excel Survey?

Answer (score 1):

You may subscribe as an alert to your email with the following steps:

1. Click on your document.
2. Choose File > Alert Me > Set alert on the document.
3. Choose your setting accordingly and DONE :)
4. However do not that, not only new subscription will trigger email, any changes will trigger email as well, sometime is quite annoying.

[image: Click Alert ME > Set alert on this document]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Forgive me as I don't have excel installed at home so I can't test to make sure it's right.  This probably requires Outlook.

```
 Sub CreateMail() 
    Dim myItem As Object 

    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

    myItem.Subject = "Mail to myself"
    myItem.To = "myself@myself.com"
    myItem.body ="stuff"

    myItem.send

End Sub
```